# My bot is online but when I pinged it, it wont reply

Tags: discord.js

So I coded a basic discord bot, the bot will reply me once I pinged it.

The bot is able to went online on the server, but when I pinged it it wont reply, The consoles didnt even log it. [the code for the ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B3E9.png) [the intents I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRGba.png)

It should respond to my ping and reply Pong!

Comment: How do you ping? And also, please don't post links to pictures to code... Just use makup and post it in the question.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking. Well I just @ the bot in my discord server

Answer (score 1):

Your code only replies to the word `ping`.
If you want to make it reply to a mention you can check if the message content is a mention like this

```js
if (message.content === `<@${client.user.id}>`) {
    // code here
}
```